# Could JAXB use the base type for a known element with an unknown type?

Tags: java, jaxb

Given a XSD like this one:

```
<!-- ... -->
    <xsd:element name="MyElement" type="ParentType" />
<!-- ... -->
<xsd:complexType name="ParentType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- ... -->
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ChildType1">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="ParentType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <!-- ... -->
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<!-- ... -->
```

could JAXB2 be configured to fall-back to the base type ParentType when it has to unmarshall a XML which contains an element of an unknown type, like in the next example:

```
<!-- ... -->
<MyElement xsi:type="ChildType2">
    <!-- ... -->
</MyElement>
<!-- ... -->
```

Normally, in this situation, JAXB throws an exception which says that ChildType2 is an unrecognised type.

Comment: +1 - JAXB can definitely leverage `xsi:type` in an inheritance hierarchy (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html).  Your question is specifically how to handle the case where `xsi:type` does not correspond to a class that JAXB is aware of?

Comment: Yes, Blaise, my question is about the case where xsi:type corresponds to a class that JAXB is not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you need, but you can use [`@XmlAnyElement`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html) to unmarshal unknown types as DOM Elements.

Consider a `Customer` class with the `extras` field annotated with a catch-all `@XmlAnyElement`.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Element> extras = new ArrayList<Element>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Element> getExtras() {
      return extras;
    }
}
```

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <salary>1000</salary>
    <age>45</age>
</customer>
```

`Salary` and `Age` are unknown types, and are stored in our extras list when we unmarshal:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
System.out.println(customer.getName());
for (Element el : customer.getExtras()) {
    System.out.println(el.getNodeName() + "->"
               + el.getTextContent());
```

Output:

```
John Doe
salary->1000
age->45
```

Comment: +1 - Also if you set `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` then your JAXB implementation will convert known types to object form:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Comment: The problem with using `@XmlAnyElement` is that you have to look through the list of elements in order to find what you need. For example, in my case, I want to be able to use JAXB even when somebody updated the XML schema with a new type that I am not aware of, but which is an extension of a known type. Also, `@XmlAnyElement` requires adding adnotated elements to any location where unknown elements might appear and I do not know this locations. I though there might be some configuration option or options which could allow this.